# Property 'platform' is declared but never used

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Why I got this warning by tslint?

```
Package name: io.ionic.starter
[18:37:16]  tslint: s:/IonicProject/VerificheNawi/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 14
        Property 'platform' is declared but never used.

  L14:    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform, public splash: SplashScreen) {
  L15:      platform.ready().then(()  => {
```

As you can see, L15 use platform...
I wonder if there is something I didn't yet understood about injection.

Comment: I think I know why, but just in case... could you please try by changing that line with this one: `this.platform.ready().then(()  => {`. If that works, let me know and I'll add an answer explaining why it happens :)

Comment: Yes, I did this as first. But it was the same.

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes. I have to put simply `platform: Platform` instead of `private platform: Platform` (or public). This would be only a reference, and warning disappears. However, I used actual platform after this...  :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved. Since it's the same as I've mentioned in the answer, could you please mark it as the accepted answer so we can close the issue?

Comment: I think I did! [I have less the 15reputation, so I can't be sure I alredy did it: I tried again]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is the line number 14. So try with this:

```
constructor(platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, public splash: SplashScreen) {
```

by omitting the `private` keyword for the platform in the constructor, we're telling Typescript **not to create a property** for it, in this component.

Why? Since you're using the platform like this: `platform.ready...` **you're not using the property from the component, but the parameter from the constructor**.

So as I see it, you could fix that in two ways:

1. Remove the `private` keyword next to the platform, in the `constructor`, in order to not create a property in the component, and just use the `platform` parameter.
2. Change `platform.ready().then(...)` by `this.platform.ready().then(..)` to use the property from the component (by using the `this` keyword).